# Modify the functioning of zipWithIndex

Tags: scala, indexing, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD which has the following values:

```
v
v v
v
v
v v
v
```

I want to index the above RDD. The way I want to index it is if a line has two values, the next line's index should be incremented by `1` so the indexed RDD would look like:

```
v, 0
v v, 1
v, 3
v, 4
v v, 5
v, 7
```

So is this even possible using spark? If it is, how do I accomplish this?

**UPDATE 1**

Also, it would be great if someone could show how to extend the zipWithIndex function and create a new function which increments the indexes of every line based on the input string for ex. `(data, index+data.length)`

Comment: What is v exactly ?

Comment: @meucaa "v" is any arbitary data. Basically they are space separated values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potentially slow, but relatively simple solution: the idea is to label these records with some IDs, *split* them so that each value is a separate record (which then can easily be enumerated using `zipWithIndex`), and then group back to original structure using the IDs we created:

```
// sample data:
val input = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  List("a"),
  List("b", "c"),
  List("d"),
  List("e", "f")
))

val result: RDD[(List[String], Long)] = input
  .zipWithIndex() // add key to each record, so we can construct them back later
  .flatMap { case (list, id) => list.map(i => (id, i)) } // "split" into individual records
  .sortByKey().zipWithIndex() // enumerate individual values
  .groupBy { case ((key, value), index) => key } // grouping by key
  .values.map { iter =>   // mapping back to the structure we want
     val list = iter.toList
     val index: Long = list.map(_._2).min
     val values: List[String] = list.map(_._1._2)
     (values, index)
   }
```

Result of which would be:

```
(List(a),0)
(List(b, c),1)
(List(d),3)
(List(e, f),4)
```